# What should __len__ be for PyTorch when generating unlimited data?

Tags: python, pytorch

Say I am trying to use PyTorch to learn the equation `y = 2x` and I want to generate an unlimited amount of data to train my model with. I am supposed to provide a `__len__` function. Here's an example below. What should it be in this case? How do I specify the number of mini-batch iterations per epoch? Do I just set a number arbitrarily?

```
import numpy as np
from torch.utils.data import Dataset

class UnlimitedData(Dataset):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        x = np.random.randint(1,10)
        y = 2 * x
        return x, y
    
    def __len__(self):
        return 1000000 # This works but is not correct
```

Comment: It sounds like you should be using an [iterable-style dataset](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html) instead of a map-style dataset.

Comment: In this question (and answers) you will find a short discussion on tradeoffs for some alternatives for what you're trying to do:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54359243/implementing-an-infinite-loop-dataset-dataloader-in-pytorch

Answer (score 3):

You should use [`torch.utils.data.IterableDataset`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.IterableDataset) instead of [`torch.utils.data.Dataset`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.Dataset). In your case it would be:

```
import torch


class Dataset(torch.utils.data.IterableDataset):
    def __init__(self, batch_size):
        super().__init__()
        self.batch_size = batch_size

    def __iter__(self):
        while True:
            x = torch.randint(1, 10, (self.batch_size,))
            y = 2 * x
            yield x, y
```

You should use batches (probably large ones), as that would speed up computations (pytorch is well suited for GPU computations on many samples at once).